# Python, Pandas: Africa/Cairo time zone doesn't apply daylight saving time (DST) in 2023

Tags: python, pandas, timezone, dst, timezone-offset

I need to localize my timestamps to have Egypt local time. The usage of DST has been stopped in Egypt since 2011. However, Egypt will reapply DST starting on 28 April 2023.

The problem is that the "Africa/Cairo" time zone in pandas didn't get this reapplication. It uses DST until 2010 but doesn't get it back in 2023. Is there a way to explicitly specify the DST transition dates when localizing timestamps in pandas other than specifying the time offset manually for each time stamp? I tried pytz but got the same problem.

```
>>> pd.Timestamp('20100501').tz_localize('Africa/Cairo')
Timestamp('2010-05-01 00:00:00+0300', tz='Africa/Cairo')

>>> pd.Timestamp('20230501').tz_localize('Africa/Cairo')
Timestamp('2023-05-01 00:00:00+0200', tz='Africa/Cairo')   # Should be +3 too
```

Comment: Wikipedia says the Egyptian government has been flip-flopping on Daylight Saving Time Try reinstalling these packages to get the latest database of when DST applies to each locality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments above.

The solution was to upgrade pytz

```
pip install -U pytz
```

Now

```
>>> pd.Timestamp('20230501').tz_localize('Africa/Cairo')
Timestamp('2023-05-01 00:00:00+0300', tz='Africa/Cairo')
```

Even without upgrading pandas or importing pytz.

Answer (score 0):

In `pandas` version 2.0.0 it seems to work just fine.
Which pandas' version do you use?

[image]

Comment: I tried upgrading pandas before posting the question. It turned out that I needed to upgrade pytz. After upgrading pytz, the tz_localize function from pandas was able to use the correct time offset.