# How to get rid of daylight saving time (DST) in Django? (Because in my country it's not being used anymore!)

Tags: python, django, timezone, dst

In my country, daylight saving time (DST) is not being applied anymore, but Django is still taking it into account. So when I choose my region in `TIME_ZONE` inside the `settings.py` file, the time is stored wrong (1-hour offset) inside the database.

**Is there any possible way to turn off the DST in Django?!**

Comment: This is likely due to an outdated dependency, see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75921330/10197418), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75856163/10197418) or [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76006466/10197418). A good start could be to run `pip install pytz --upgrade` in the Python environment you use for your django developement.

Comment: @FObersteiner
thank you but this didn't work! the data in my PostgreSQL are still showing wrong time :(

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [list of time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) and see if there's one that matches yours only without a DST value.

Comment: Thank you. I checked the list, it's unfortunately unique!